# How to disable UAC on a domain controller?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, domain-controller, uac

I need to disable UAC on a Windows Server 2008 R2 domain controller, but I can't access its settings through the usual path (Control Panel -> User Accounts -> User Accounts), because a DC doesn't have a local user database, so the "User Accounts" icon in the Control Panel simply doesn't work.

How can I access the UI for UAC settings on a domain controller?

---

I know I can use a GPO for this, but I'd prefer to manually configure it on this single server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do it from a command prompt:

```
runas /user:DOMAIN\youraccount "REG ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v EnableLUA /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f"
```

Comment: Or through Regedit. Good.